# should I freeze a two-day refrigarated meat sauce?

Tags: meat, freezing

I have fixed a pot of turkey meat sauce and a pot of turkey meat balls and I did not have a chance to freeze right away, which I usually do, they have been in the refrigerator for two days... Is it still safe to bag and freeze?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a sauce should last 3-4 days at least in the refrigerator (based on comparing to [Still Tasty's](http://www.stilltasty.com/fooditems/index/18577) turkey soup or stew category, which is a conservative match; plain spaghetti sauce indicates 7-10 days but this probably not based on poultry).

This clock is based on refrigerated time; freezing essentially stops the clock while the food is fully frozen.

So yes, it should be safe to freeze your sauce.